# Broadcast Receiver not working on boot since Android 8

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app registers a BroadcastReceiver for the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent. Every time the user places a call, the app takes an action (like logging the call). This used to work fine in older versions of Android. Since, Android 8, the BroadcastReceiver only captures this intent for a few hours after the app is started. It doesn't capture the intent on a reboot either. Need help in understanding what has changed and how to resolve this.

Manfest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <receiver android:name="com.example.OutgoingCallInterceptor">                          // 5
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">                                  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />  

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OutgoingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```